# Yum security model OR Why can a hostile proxy deny updates without a warning?

Tags: security, yum

A friend of mine just had the strangest kind of problem where his Fedora 20 would not update to (or even find) the current kernel 3.16.3 (and incidentally also not update the [vulnerable bash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528101/what-is-the-cve-2014-6271-bash-vulnerability-and-how-do-i-fix-it) version). After clearing caches, comparing his and my config files and a lot of head scratching I finally remembered he was using a VPN and asked him to turn it off and try again. It worked flawless outside the VPN. My guess is that the vpn enforces http proxying with an aggressive cache.

That got me thinking about the security assertions `yum` can give its user. Apparently it can not detect replay attacks on the repository database, as he did not get any warning or error message about a stale repository state. I would have assumed the repository overview was time stamped and signed regularly or fetched over HTTPS (or a hash of the database would be fetched over HTTPS to reduce the bandwidth of the encrypted traffic).

I know that signatures on the individual packages are checked, so I can at least be assured that no package can be installed on my system that was not authored by a trusted party. But how about partial updates? Can a malicious proxy or mirror selectively deny package updates? E.g. never update the vulnerable bash package but forward every other update so I won't get suspicious about not getting any updates at all?

Or even worse, can an attacker even selectively *downgrade* packages? E.g. re-install the heartbleed susceptible openssl package?

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering from the perspecting of `apt`, but I believe this is all the same for `yum`.

Updates are fetched over HTTP or FTP, not HTTPS. The idea is that the payload doesn't need to be encrypted, only unmodified, so "sufficient" security is achieved by a PGP signature on the index. But the replay attack is a problem!

In order to be scalable, updates and indices must fetched from a "dumb mirror" system, so the mirrors can't do per-connection computations. Theoretically, it would be possible to use a second system just to fetch the index and use dumb mirrors only for the bulk data.

Obviously, it is impossible to guarantee that you can connect with the server. If you trust your local system's clock, you *could* check a timestamp that is included as part of the PGP signature. This would require a *little* bit of extra infrastructure to guarantee that the signature is regenerated daily even if the contents don't change, but that would be a good idea for detecting stale mirrors anyway.

For the last part of the question - no, it is not possible to force a downgrade. A fundamental aspect of package management is that if the remote repo contains an older version than what you currently have, it does nothing.

Comment: Thx for your answer. IIRC apt is different to yum in that it does not sign the individual packages, but the package list / index (which contains hashes of the packages). Part of my question arises from the uncertainty whether the authors of yum deemed it necessary to also sign the index (given the individual packages are already signed). If they don't (contrary to apts behaviour) then an attacker can serve a malicious index that contains every updated package, except a few key vulnerable ones.

Comment: Regarding downgrades: In some situations, downgrading packages could be a feature in itself, if the new package contains buggy software (cf. ios 8.0.1). But its probably a far fetched worry.

Comment: Downgrading packages is a feature provided in a way that still appears as an update. In Debian, they use an addition "epoch number" which appears before the rest of the version (2.0 aka 0:2.0 is less than 1:1.0), although on occasion you instead get a version number like '9.3.2really9.1.27'

Comment: That's certainly a good design. I'm not sure whether RPMs have an epoch equivalent, though. `rpm -q bash -i` shows nothing of that kind.